# JSF and partial validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I wonder if there is a trick to validate all fields in a form except one ?

Something like :

```
<p:remoteCommand process="@form^F100"  .... />
```

Obviously, this doesn't work...

If I have 100 fields in a form, is there any way or shortcut to validate all exception F100 for example ?

Am I doomed to use

```
<p:remoteCommand process="F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 .... F99"  .... />
```

?

Comment: Have you tried to put them in two separate forms?

Comment: @Alexandre : no but I have multiple commandButton which validate some different fields inside same form so I have to keep only 1 form

Comment: You can play with forms and change your process="@form1 @form2" or only process="@form1" for example.

Comment: but how to do where some commandButton validate "inter fields" ? For example [F1,F2,F3] ; [F2]; [F1,F4] and so on ? I can't nest forms I think ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [PrimeFaces Selectors (PFS)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) for this. This allows you using [jQuery CSS selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in `process` and `update` attributes of PrimeFaces ajax components. You could for example use a `noprocess` class on the component which you'd like to skip and use `:not(.noprocess)` selector.

Your particular requirement can then be solved as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    ...
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... />
    <h:inputText ... styleClass="noprocess" />
    <p:remoteCommand ... process="@(form :not(.noprocess))"/>
</h:form>
```

This example will process the entire form expect of inputs having `class="noprocess"` in the client side.

Comment: Just to specify my requirement for information : I use p:captcha component and reCaptcha doesn't support partial page update so I don't want to refresh it via Ajax but with `Recaptcha.reload()` method